# How to correctly unit test Express 4 server with Jest

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

Trying to get a better understanding of it, I am testing this simple Express server (v 4 ) setup code :

**server.js**

```js
    import express from 'express';
    import router from './routes';

    const app = express();
    app.use(router);

    const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
      var port = this.address().port;
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
      console.log('Example app listening on port %s!', port);
    });

    export default app; // as suggested by Ron
```

with the following router

**routes.js**

```js
    var express = require('express');
    var defaultController = require('./controllers/defaultController');

    var router = express.Router();

    router.get('/', defaultController.getHome);

    module.exports = router;
```

it's clean ( eslinted) and running well with yarn start

I wrote ( copy/paste from tuts .. written in 2015) the following spec to test server.js with Jest and SuperTest

**server.spec.js**

```js
    var request = require('supertest');

    describe('loading express', function () {
        var server; // http server object

        beforeEach(function () {
            delete require.cache[require.resolve('../src/server')];
            server = require('../src/server');
        });

        afterEach(function () {
            server.close();
        });

        it('responds to /', function testSlash(done) {
            request(server)
              .get('/')
              .expect(200, done);
        });

        it('404 everything else', function testPath(done) {
            request(server)
              .get('/foo/bar')
              .expect(404, done);
        });
    });
```

But it's failing...  with type error on `.get()`.

> TypeError: app.address is not a function

and type error on `server.close()`

> TypeError: server.close is not a function

Here is the full console.log

**$ yarn test**

```bash
        yarn run v1.9.4
        $ jest --runInBand --verbose
         FAIL  test/server.spec.js
          loading express
            ✕ responds to / (275ms)
            ✕ 404 everything else (1ms)

          ● loading express › responds to /

            TypeError: app.address is not a function

              16 |     it('responds to /', function testSlash(done) {
              17 |         request(server)
            > 18 |           .get('/')
                 |            ^
              19 |           .expect(200, done);
              20 |     });
              21 |

              at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test.serverAddress (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:55:18)
              at new Test (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:36:12)
              at Object.obj.(anonymous function) [as get] (node_modules/supertest/index.js:25:14)
              at Object.get (test/server.spec.js:18:12)

          ● loading express › responds to /

            TypeError: server.close is not a function

              11 |
              12 |     afterEach(function () {
            > 13 |         server.close();
                 |                ^
              14 |     });
              15 |
              16 |     it('responds to /', function testSlash(done) {

              at Object.close (test/server.spec.js:13:16)

          ● loading express › 404 everything else

            TypeError: app.address is not a function

              22 |     it('404 everything else', function testPath(done) {
              23 |         request(server)
            > 24 |           .get('/foo/bar')
                 |            ^
              25 |           .expect(404, done);
              26 |     });
              27 | });

              at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test.serverAddress (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:55:18)
              at new Test (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:36:12)
              at Object.obj.(anonymous function) [as get] (node_modules/supertest/index.js:25:14)
              at Object.get (test/server.spec.js:24:12)

          ● loading express › 404 everything else

            TypeError: server.close is not a function

              11 |
              12 |     afterEach(function () {
            > 13 |         server.close();
                 |                ^
              14 |     });
              15 |
              16 |     it('responds to /', function testSlash(done) {

              at Object.close (test/server.spec.js:13:16)

          console.log src/server.js:11
            Example app listening on port 3000!

        Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
        Tests:       2 failed, 2 total
        Snapshots:   0 total
        Time:        1.062s
        Ran all test suites.
        Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

        This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

Comment: Split apart the app and the server; supertest just wants the Express app object, and you don't need to actually listen on a port for those tests.

Comment: I tried  it. (. export default app;  ) but got same errors ...  in my server.js

Comment: FYI .. I tried to follow this tut :  https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/how-to-correctly-unit-test-express-server/

Comment: Note that the tutorial doesn't use `this` to access the server. But I'd still suggest keeping the app separate from the server, it avoids things like port conflicts (if you want to run the tests while the dev server is running).

Comment: Yes , you're right ... I updated my code .. however I got the same errors...

Comment: There is so much wrong with the tutorial I don't even know where to start(not your fault), for a start that's not a fricken unit test, that's an integration test - anywho - change your server.js to export default server?

Answer (score 0):

For error:

> TypeError: app.address is not a function

and

> TypeError: server.close is not a function

Change

```js
var server;
beforeEach(function() {
  delete require.cache[require.resolve('./server')];
  server = require('./server');
});
```

To:

```js
var server;

beforeEach(function() {
  delete require.cache[require.resolve('./server')];
  server = require('./server').default;
});
```

Since you start HTTP server in `server.js` file which means when you execute `require('./server')` statement in your test file, the server will be started. You should close the server after all tests done. Otherwise, it will throw an error:

> Error [ERR_SERVER_NOT_RUNNING]: Server is not running.

Change

```js
afterEach(function(done) {
  server.close(done);
});
```

To:

```js
afterAll(function(done) {
  server.close(done);
});
```

The `app` object created by `express` has no `.close()` method, but [http.Server](https://devdocs.io/node~10_lts/http#http_class_http_server) does.

Change:

```js
const server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  var port = this.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening on port %s!', port);
});

export default app;
```

To:

```js
const server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  var port = this.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening on port %s!', port);
});

export default server;
```

Integration test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
☁  jest-codelab [master] ⚡  npx jest --coverage --verbose /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/53920812/server.spec.js
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/53920812/server.spec.js
  loading express
    ✓ responds to / (741ms)
    ✓ 404 everything else (6ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/53920812/server.js:428
    Example app listening on port 3000!

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 routes.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 server.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.865s, estimated 10s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/53920812

Comment: Thank you for sharing. What's the purpose of closing the server after all tests? I want to close it after each test so my in-memory database is reset and my tests are independent. But if I do it on `afterEach()` I get `ERR_SERVER_NOT_RUNNING`.

Answer (score 0):

Supertest isn't looking for a server, it's looking for an app. It then takes that app and runs its own server for the test. Separate your `server.js` file into two files:

`app.js`:

```js
import express from 'express';
import router from './routes';

const app = express();
app.use(router);

const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var port = this.address().port;
  /* eslint-disable no-console */
  console.log('Example app listening on port %s!', port);
});

export default app;
```

`server.js`:

```js
import app from './app';

const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var port = this.address().port;
  /* eslint-disable no-console */
  console.log('Example app listening on port %s!', port);
});

export default server;
```

Then you can change your test to something like this:

```js
var request = require('supertest');

describe('loading express', function () {
    const app = require('../app'); // Or whereever your app is

    it('responds to /', function testSlash(done) {
        request(app)
          .get('/')
          .expect(200, done);
    });

    it('404 everything else', function testPath(done) {
        request(app)
          .get('/foo/bar')
          .expect(404, done);
    });
});
```

Because Supertest is running its own instance, you don't have another competing server you have to close everytime. Now when you're ready to go to production mode, you just run `node server`.